# Time conversion between ruby on rails and javascript vice versa?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to convert ruby time to javascript time and vice versa?

Ruby on rails :

```
 Time.now
```

Javascript :

```
 new Date()
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Perhaps the most reliable way is to use seconds since the epoch for ruby, and milliseconds for JavaScript.

In ruby:

```rb
t = Time.now
# => 2014-03-12 11:18:29 -0700
t.to_f * 1000 # convert to milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
# => 1394648309130.185
```

This value can be directly given to the JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor:

```js
var d = new Date(1394648309130.185)
d // Wed Mar 12 2014 11:18:29 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

d.getTime() // 1394648309130 (Fractions of a millisecond are dropped)
```

The output of [`d.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) divided by 1000 can be given to ruby's [`Time.at()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html#method-c-at):

```rb
Time.at( 1394648309130 / 1000.0 )
# => 2014-03-12 11:18:29 -0700
```

Comment: Time.zone.at( 1394648309000 / 1000.0 )

Answer (score 8):

From jquery to rails:

```
"Wed Mar 12 2014 23:45:39 GMT+0530 (IST)".to_time
```

Answer (score 7):

These methods in both are equivalent, use either:

For Ruby:

```
Time.now.httpdate
```

For Javascript:

```
new Date().toUTCString()
```

Output for both:

```
Tue, 04 Jul 2017 14:18:31 GMT
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it will help you :

ruby date to javascript date conversion:

```
<script>
  var date_str = <% Date.today %>;
  var date_obj = new Date(date_str);
</script>
```

javascript date to ruby date conversion:

use this code in ruby class.

fetch date from params attributes.

```
date_str = params[:js_date]
date_obj = Date.parse(date_str)
```

for more info you can refer:

```
 http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html
 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp
```

Comment: By considering the date object in this both languages,We need to consider the parsing mechanism,Suppose if we are giving new Date(1,1,2015) then we will give the result like this 1-February-2015,but in ruby its take as 1-January-2015,  it showing js counting months from Zero

Answer (score 2):

Use strftime to get miliseconds:

```
<script>
  date = new Date(<%= DateTime.now.strftime '%Q' %>);
</script>
```

And parse back to Ruby using to_date:

```
params[:date].to_date
```

to_date accepts few formats:

```
'3-2-2001'
'03/02/2001'
'2001-02-03'
'3rd Feb 2001'
'20010203'
```

Comment: Ups, actually it should be that way :) Question is about date, so to_date is proper one.