# How to parse date with time zone from a custom string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

In cookies I store a date returned by JS `new Date()` in the following format:

```
Thu Oct 29 2015 15:46:19 GMT 0100 (CET)
```

How can I parse this in Rails to get a `DateTime` object with correct time zone? `.to_datetime` returns `2015-10-29T15:46:19+00:00` which has incorrect time zone.

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360332/time-conversion-between-ruby-on-rails-and-javascript-vice-versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally JS `new Date` returns like this.

```
(new Date).toString(); // => "Fri Oct 30 2015 00:36:43 GMT+0900 (JST)"
```

I guess your JS datetime string is missing `+` after `GMT`.
This works perfectly

```
'Thu Oct 29 2015 15:46:19 GMT+0100 (CET)'.to_datetime # => Thu, 29 Oct 2015 15:46:19 +0100
```