# Ruby on Rails - Plotting dates using lazy highcharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I am working on financial savings calculator as a test project to help me get better at RoR.

I have created two objects - User (through Devise gem) and Saving (which belongs to the User).

In my web app the user signs up and inputs a savings start date (:start_date) and savings end date (:end_date) as well as a goal value (:goal).

After signing up the user can input savings through a new form and select the date they put aside money (:week) and the amount (:amount).

Then on the show page of the Savings controller the user can view a graph of their savings they have input to date. Here I use LazyHighCharts to handle the plotting of the values.

Now I am having trouble implementing two features into the show page of this app and they both involve dates:

1) At the moment the savings are plotting with with integer values on the x-axis, I can't seem to get highcharts to understand that the x values are dates. see attached screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TXgT.jpg

2) I want to create a Goal spline on highcharts with two values - start_date (with an amount of 0) and end_date (with an amount of :goal).

I have pasted the SavingsController code below to show my working so far, my view file simply has a render of @charts on it.

```
def show

@start_date = User.where(id: params[:user_id]).pluck(:start_date)
@end_date = User.where(id: params[:user_id]).pluck(:end_date)
@goal = User.where(id: params[:user_id]).pluck(:goal)

# create an array with a 0 value for start_date and the goal value for  
# end_date, use this to plot in highcharts


# Find the saving data from the DB and associated week value, sort ASC

@data = Saving.where(user_id: params[:user_id]).pluck(:week,:amount)

@data_sorted = @data.sort {|x,y| x[0] <=> y[0] }

# Prepare highcharts with data from database
@chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.title({:text=>"Savings Progress"})
  f.xAxis [{type: 'datetime'}]

  f.yAxis [
   {title: {text: "Money Saved ($)" }}]
  f.xAxis [
   {title: {text: "Weeks Since Start of Saving" }}]

 # f.labels(:items=>[:html=>"Savings Over Weeks", :style=>{:left=>"40px", :top=>"8px", :color=>"black"} ])      

  f.series(:type=> 'spline',:name=> 'Savings to Date', :data=> @data_sorted)

 end
 end
```

Comment: How are your dates parsed? If they don't use a correct output for JS, it just can't parse it properly. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360332/time-conversion-between-ruby-on-rails-and-javascript-vice-versa)  and HighCharts documentation [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time) and click 'View Options' to reveal the code for xAxis as well as the correct DateTime format.

Comment: I may be deluded but I was under the impression that because im using lazyhighcharts with the ruby gem, I am not actually using JS? Or does the gem just convert the ruby to JS?

I have tried to parse the dates into different formats but keep getting errors, is there an issue with the date being in an array format?